# Match any group of characters before a line break sign

Tags: javascript, regex, newline

I am trying to match any group of characters until a line break like this: `\n`. I want to be able to access all groups matched then.

The text I am using to look for my regular expression is like this :

```
foo foo!\n *bar bar*\n *foo :* foo bar\n*foo :* 32 foo bar\n*Bar :* 37 foo foo\n*Time :* 11:00:00-14:00:00\n*Date :* 2016-12-23\n*Foo :* \n*bar* : 06XXXXXXXX
```

For now, I tried multiple solutions and the best working is this regex:

```
/([^\\n])\w+/
```

but it it still not perfect. It doesn't take the special chars nor spaces into account.

Comment: The `s.match(/.+/g)`  should be enough. Or even `s.split("\n")`. Can there be CR symbols in the string?

Comment: Your `[^\\n]` is going to match anything except a real backslash and a real n, which is almost certainly not what you want. You might try `[^\n], but unfortunately `\n` does not work within a character set.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to is match at least one (`+`) char that is **not** new-line (`\n`):

```js
s = 'foo foo!\n *bar bar*\n *foo :* foo bar\n*foo :* 32 foo bar\n*Bar :* 37 foo foo\n*Time :* 11:00:00-14:00:00\n*Date :* 2016-12-23\n*Foo :* \n*bar* : 06XXXXXXXX'

console.log(s.match(/([^\n]+)/g))
```

Comment: The funny thing is that your regexp would still work if you replaced the `[^\n]` with a dot, and by the way you don't need the parens either.

Comment: @torazaburo, there are many ways write regex things :) a dot indeed is one of them :) btw, a voteup will be much appreciated!

Comment: You should double check it. The `\n` is indeed meaningful in character class. Run my example :)